# Android Studio "Windows Universal C Runtime" issue on Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: android, windows, flutter, android-studio

I created a brand new flutter app in Android Studio 4.2.1. It is a default counter app which you get when you create a flutter app. When I run the app I get the below error -

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

In my build.gradle file gradle dependency is - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

I checked other stackoverflow posts which mentioned this similar issue but that suggested installing Windows Universal C Runtime. However, I am running the app on a Windows 10 machine which should have Windows Universal C Runtime by default.

I checked the microsoft website as well and it has installables for Windows Universal C Runtime but those are for older versions of Windows like Windows7, Windows8 etc.

I tried running the application using VS Code as well but I get the same error.

Any ideas as to what is causing this issue on Windows 10?

Comment: Any update for this ?

Comment: I am still getting the same issue... Are you seeing it as well?